# Store integer value into a variable from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this little issue , I'm trying to get a number from my firebase database, the thing is that I can get the number but it seems that I'm doing something wrong storing it inside an integer.

What I'm trying to do is to have the number from firebase and compare it to my version number of my app, so I can tell my users to update the app if the apps is higher than my current version

here is my code

```
mDatabase.child("version").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               // System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                //Log.e("Versiondeapp",""+dataSnapshot.getValue());
                int ultimaVersion = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if(versionCode!=ultimaVersion){
                    ActualizarAppAlert();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and my problem is here

```
int ultimaVersion = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

it seems that I can't store that number value from firebase to an integer variable

My current stack error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

PS: I solved my problem doing this
`Integer.valueOf(datasnapshot.getvalue().tostring());`

Comment: Please add your database structure and the lines where you are using `Integer.intValue()`.

Comment: hi @AlexMamo im not using Integer.intValue()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see that it's not exactly related to Firebase.
I think you need first to check why you object is null and than just convert it to int (that's what you need) with:

```
Integer.valueOf(dataSnapShot.getValue())
```

In addition take in consideration that according to [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue--):
The possible types returned from getValue() are:

```
Boolean  
Long  
Double  
Map<String, Object>  
List<Object>
```

Comment: if i do a Log.e with datasnapshot.getvalue , im getting the value "34" , the same one in my database

Comment: Ok. When you wrote "34" you meant its String?

Comment: its an integer , not an string

Comment: Please try Integer.valueOf(datasnapshot.getvalue()).

Comment: Rather it should be `(Long) datasnapshot.getValue()` as it is documented which you have mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
int ultimaVersion = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

to:

```
int ultimaVersion = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely sure that the value is going to be an int number then this will work for you.

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getValue()!= null){
    int ultimaVersion = ((Long) dataSnapshot.getValue()).intValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

kotlin

```
val result = dataSnapshot.value.toString()
desiredVariable = result.toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mDatabase.child("version").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                //Log.e("Versiondeapp",""+dataSnapshot.getValue());
                int ultimaVersion =  ds.getValue(Integer.class);
                if(versionCode!=ultimaVersion){
                    ActualizarAppAlert();
            }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Try this out..

Comment: There is no `int.class` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
package rifqi.firebaseiotawal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import static android.R.id.message;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView txt;


   private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
private  DatabaseReference mchild = myRef.child("adc");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
txt.setText("hai");
    }
@Override
    protected void onStart () {
    super.onStart();
    mchild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Integer adc = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                txt.setText(""+  adc);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

You can try this code, its work for me...im put **""** at front of variable **adc** as type of data

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
int ultimaVersion = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue()+"");
```

*Here we have just appended an empty string to the Long value so as to make a whole string and convert it all to an integer using parseInt*

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
int variableName=documentSnapshot.getLong("field name").intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but i have to share this it will help others. So, if you store integer number to Firebase Database, it will always return as a Long Object.
The accepted answer is a right solution but what if you want return object as a model class with different variables?

So here it is you can use this method to get object as model class,

```
   //pass datasnapShot and your.class as object
   public static Object snapshotToClass(DataSnapshot snapshot, Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {
         
         if (object == null) {
             throw new NullPointerException();
         }

         Field[] fields = object.getClass().getFields();

         if (fields.length > 0) {
              for (Field field : fields) {
                   String name = field.getName();
                   if (snapshot.hasChild(name)) {
                        Object o = snapshot.child(name).getValue();
                        field.set(object, o);
                   }
              }
          }

    return object;
}
```