# Can I store Int value inside Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, int

I have store resource values in variables, and now I want to store this variable inside the Firebase database but the data type is Integer (int) and I don't know can we store an integer in Firebase or not.

I want to store below two variables of Integer type inside Firebase Database:

```
int textColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.black, null);
int textSize = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text10sp));
```

Comment: Firebase provides support for long, You can type case it later into integer

Comment: How to do it with these variables.

Comment: Follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423405/store-integer-value-into-a-variable-from-firebase

Comment: For `textColor` save a hex code String . for text Size save `long` pixel size ..

Comment: Did you try saving these values to the database already? What was the problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I store Int value inside Firebase database?

Sure you can, in a property of type `Long`, which is a [supported data-type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). An `int` value will always fit in a `Long`.

Comment: he can use directly `Integer` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types

Comment: @mohamedaouledissa The link you have provided is for Cloud Firestore, while the OP is asking a question about Firebase Realtime Database. Both are apart of Firebase but actually are two **different** products.

Comment: The OP is clearly asking about firebase database.

Comment: @mohamedaouledissa The OP has set as a tag "firebase-realtime-database". There is no simple "Firebase database". There is [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). There are **two** different products. You have added a link regarding Firestore, which is **not** correct!

Comment: I didn't mind the tag. Indeed they are two different products. Apologies for the downvote will update accordingly! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen I did it. and Yes I am using Realtime Database.

Comment: Yes your answer is working fine for me. I stored the data inside firebase with long data type, and then cast it later to int in adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly cast your `int` as `Integer`

```
Integer.valueOf(textColor)
Integer.valueOf(textSize)
```

Comment: @KamranKhan How to accept an answer that you did **not** even try it?

Comment: I solved my problem earlier. I was working on it many hourse. I studied Firebase Docs... and This is because I'll find it quickly next time if I forgot.

Comment: @KamranKhan Can you please explain how did this answer respond to your question "Can I store Int value inside Firebase database"?

Comment: Actually @alex-mamo is right. You should accept the answer that best  resolves your question. If none of the answers did and you have  figured out a  solution by yourself, please go ahead and answer your own question and mark it as accepted. I would like to professionally approach your to do  so. If alex-mamo answer solves your problem please accept it instead of mine. Many thanks.

Comment: I did not try Integer.valueOf(textColor)... I tried Alex Mamo Answer and it works fine. I stored my data in firebase with long data type.