# How to save mobile number in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an placement app where I need to save mobile number in fire-base database so that I can retrieve it later but if I wish to store in "int" datatype  then my app crashes and if "string" data format is used for mobile number then app works fine. But I want to store mobile number in int or any other form so that I can retrieve it later.
In what datatype should I store mobile number in fire-base?
So please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store integer value into a variable from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423405/store-integer-value-into-a-variable-from-firebase)

Comment: No Sir. My question is , In what datatype should I save mobile number in fire-base because it is accepting "long" datatype value but not the "int".

Comment: Phone numbers aren’t integers. What’s wrong with using a string?

Answer (score 3):

Integer types should only be used when storing a value that represents some quantity or measurement.  A phone number is not that at all.  A phone number is best stored as a string.